# How to run python / pytube code on iOS device?

Tags: python, iphone, mobile, kivy, pytube

I built a simple app using pytube with which you can download Youtube videos.

That's the code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from pytube import YouTube
import os

class AVPlayer(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1

        self.user = TextInput(
            padding_y = (20, 20),
            size_hint = (1, 0.5),
        )
        self.window.add_widget(self.user)
        self.window.size_hint = (0.6, 0.2)
        self.window.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

        self.button = Button(
            text="Download",
            size_hint = (1, 0.5),
            background_color = '#398AFF'
            
        )
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)

        return self.window


    def callback(self, event):
        url = self.user.text
        my_video = YouTube(url)

        #get Video Title
        print("*********************Video Title************************")
        print(my_video.title)

        #get Thumbnail Image
        print("********************Tumbnail Image***********************")
        print(my_video.thumbnail_url)

        #download
        print("********************Download video*************************")
        #my_video = my_video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
        my_video = my_video.streams.filter(res="360p").first().download()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AVPlayer().run()
```

It just runs on my desktop. But I would like to have it as a mobile app on my iPhone. I could create an iOS app using swift but there is no library like pytube.
I guess kivy would be possible, too, but I do not like it.. so is there an other alternative?

Comment: My suggestion would be to just make a web application so you can use it on any device.

Comment: Also the question is about how to run the code on iOS. Please update the title accordingly.

Comment: A tricky option is that you embed a copy of Python within your app so run the Python interpreter inside your app’s process (see https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2328/_index.html) but your swift app embedding Python may not pass App Store Review for its clauses 2.7 and 2.8